# Input когда активный закрывает клавиатуру на телефоне

Tags: input, клавиатура

Может кто-то сталкивался, есть поле поиска , когда на телефоне пытаешься установить фокус (сделать активным, установить курсор) - клавиатура открывается и сразу закрывается. Нужно чтобы клавиатура НЕ закрывалась (поскольку нельзя набрать слово для поиска). Пробовал на JQ реализовать так:

```
    $('input[name=search]').click(function() {
      $(this).focus();
 });
```

не помогает, пробовал вставить

```
setTimeout(function(){
              $(this).focus();
            }, 2000);
```

тоже проблему не решило. Как устранить такой баг.

Comment: Нет, ни разу не сталкивался. Поле поиска где? Телефон какой? Вы уверены, что проблема именно в сайте, а не в напрочь баганутой кривой китайской прошивке телефона? // Ну или как вариант вы недостаточно подробно объяснили проблему, и в итоге никто ничего не понял

Comment: Отсутствует пример для воспроизведения проблемы.

Comment: На сайте есть поле поиска, если его открыть на любом телефоне появляется такой баг, хотя на Планшетах - его нет.

Comment: Составьте и поместите в тексте вопроса [mcve], потому что мы до сих пор не понимаем, о чём речь

Comment: Есть сайт, если его открыть на телефоне и попытаться "встать" (сделать активным, войти в поле, нажать на поле) на поле поиска для ввода поисковой фразы - сразу же появляется (всплывает, отображается, выезжает ) клавиатура и через секунду исчезает (прячется, уезжает). При чем на планшетах - такого бага нет

Comment: Проблема решена. Ошибка была вот в чем на экране менее 991px блоки менялись местами - реализовано было на JQ. Код переписан (блоки меняются) на CSS (использован flex).

Answer (score 1):

Решение было найдено скролить страницу вверх когда Input получил фокус

```
$('body').on('focus','#my_input',function(){
    $('.parent_input').animate({scrollTop:150},800);
});
```